# How to see the stacktrace of a .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, stack-trace

I have a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Windows application in the production that has no access to Visual Studio (standard edition), and the only thing they can install is the [Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_Express) edition, which does not have the Just-In-Time Debugging option (the one which has the debug button when it crashes). So I was just wondering if there is a Windows application debugging tool or something else that I can run or attach to see stacktraces. I also enabled [PDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) in my application, but it does not provide any more information, so I can trace my crashes (caused by unhandled exceptions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use windbg and sos.dll

Comment: That can be hard for even intermediate developers. Maybe they can use DebugDiag or other tools to generate a crash dump and analyze with WinDbg. Then a simple "analyze -v" is enough to print out exception information.

Comment: Is it possible to produce the line number from Windbg? Cause I can get the method name, but not the line number.

Comment: Only if you have symbols and I THINK it has to be built in debug mode too.

Answer (score 6):

If you are catching exceptions, the Exception object contains the stack trace: [Exception.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx). Also, you have access to it with [Environment.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx).

In the code below there is also an event handler for unhandled exceptions which will write the exception, including the stack trace, to the event log.

```
// Sample for the Environment.StackTrace property
using System;

class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
          new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptions);

        Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: '{0}'", Environment.StackTrace);
        throw new Exception("Fatal Error");
    }

    static void UnhandledExceptions(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        string source = "SOTest";
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(source))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, "Application");
        }

        System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        log.Source = source;

        log.WriteEntry(e.ExceptionObject.ToString(), 
                       System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
```

Comment: so can I print out some unhanded exception as well?

Comment: Yes. You could use logging frameworks to write them to error logs too.

Comment: @paradisonoir - I added an unhandled exception event handler, which writes the log (including stack trace) to the event log.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979205.aspx)

Comment: Does it give a nice output for the content of Stacktrace? like class and line number, cause my crashes are unhandled ones.

Comment: @paradisonoir: Fyi, line numbers are only available if you have the pdb of the assemblies.  Else, you'll just get the stack location and method names.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a free profiler that solves the OP's problem, namely displaying the stacktrace. For the record, here's a link to CLR Profiler 2.0: http://tinyurl.com/ClrProfiler2

Answer (score 1):

The stacktraces of .NET application exceptions are logged in your Event Viewer under Applications.

This link throws a 404:

[alt text http://eduncan911.com/blog/thumbnail/exception-in-iis-stackoverflow-logs.png](http://eduncan911.com/blog/thumbnail/exception-in-iis-stackoverflow-logs.png)

Comment: I think you will find they only end up here if you log them yourself, when an exception is thrown!

Comment: I get exceptions in my apps, that I do not handle showing here.

Comment: My ASP.net applications also automatically log unhandled exceptions to the eventlog. No code needed.

Comment: Well, I am running a Window Application, so do you think it can be helpful for them as well. My crashes are for unhandled exceptions though

Comment: Ah crap, I missed that part (using Windows App).  I do not have enough experience to know if windows apps will show up in the event viewer.  I would imagine it does.  Just take a quick look.

Comment: For WinForms or WPF applications, event log entries are different, and call stacks are not available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [EQATEC Tracer](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/tracer/guide) could help you out.

Comment: I started my application with it, but it does not have any output of my stacktrace after a crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

- *[.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/thankyou.aspx?familyId=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec&displayLang=en)*
- *[.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/thankyou.aspx?familyId=1aef6fce-6e06-4b66-afe4-9aad3c835d3d&displayLang=en)*

.NET Framework 2.0 SDK ships with Microsoft CLR Debugger. It works similar to Visual Studio debugger (though source files are readonly), so you can give it a try.

Comment: You can also add global exception handlers to your application. 

http://blogs.msdn.com/lexli/archive/2009/04/28/how-to-handle-net-unhandled-exceptions-gracefully.aspx